# Text-align and GTK CSS

Tags: gtk3, gtkcssprovider

This is interesting, according to the [docs](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-properties.html) there isn't a text-align and trying it gives

```
gi.repository.GLib.Error: gtk-css-provider-error-quark: <data>:3:14'text-align' is not a valid property name (3)
```

Is there an alternative to text-align: left/right/etc for buttons or other widgets with GTK CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have updated with answer -

```
self.builder.get_object("button1").set_alignment(0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try the "gtk_widget_set_halign" function.  Following is an example.

```
gtk_widget_set_halign(GTK_WIDGET(button), GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
```

The first parameter is the widget that you want to affect (e.g. a button).  The second parameter is the type of alignment that you want to perform within the widget.  The second parameter has five pre-defined constants:

GTK_ALIGN_BASELINE

GTK_ALIGN_CENTER

GTK_ALIGN_END

GTK_ALIGN_FILL

GTK_ALIGN_START

I hope that is clear.

Regards.